# Getting error in implementation of heap sort

Tags: java

I'm trying to create and sort a heap using this array in Java. I keep getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 42
>   at HeapSort.exchange(HeapSort.java:28)
>   at HeapSort.Max_Heapify(HeapSort.java:22)
>   at HeapSort.Build_Heap at HeapSort.Sort(HeapSort.java:36)
>   at HeapSort.main(HeapSort.java:46)

I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

```
public class HeapSort {
    public static int n;
    public static int[] a;
    public static int largest;

    public static void Build_Heap(int[] a){
        n = a.length-1;
        for(int i = n/2; i >= 0; i--){
            Max_Heapify(a,i);
        }
    }
    public static void Max_Heapify(int[] a,int i){
        int left = 2*i;
        int right = 2*i +1;

        if(left <= n && a[left] > a[i])
            largest = left;
        if(right <=n && a[right] > a[largest])
            largest = right;
        if(largest != i)
            exchange (a[i],a[largest]);
        Max_Heapify(a,largest);
    }


    private static void exchange(int i, int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public static void Sort(int[] a0){
        a = a0;
        Build_Heap(a);

        for(int i = n; i > 0; i--){
            exchange(0,i);
            n = n-1;
            Max_Heapify(a,0);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a1 = {3,55,6,42,34,56,34};
        Sort(a1);
        for(int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++){
            System.out.print(a1[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? And what is the purpose of `n = n-1` inside the `for` loop in `Sort ` method?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error in `exchange()`. The parameters `i` and `j` for that method look like to be indexes of the array `a`. But, you are calling the method `exchange(a[i],a[largest])` which is passing the value of from the array at indexes `i` and `largest` instead of passing the actual indexes `i` and `largest` to the method.

Try calling exchange like `exchange(i,largest)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `exchange` call (on line 22) in `Max_Heapify()` is given the values of the array at those locations instead of the locations (the indexes, `i` and `largest`) that can be anything, in this example, 42 which is larger than the array to be sorted length,

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.